# Pass Strongly Typed data and JSON string to controller from $.ajax funtion in View

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-ajaxq

I have ASP.NET-MVC5 application. I have strongly typed form and I successfully can pass back to controller. Now I have JavaScript array variable that I need to also send so I need to post back both information from view to controller using .$ajax post function.

I have update code as to add avaScript array variable, since then I am getting null value for form data.

### View

```
var AdditionalTenentList = {
    StudentUWLID: []
};

 $('#CreateStudentRentingApplicationForm').submit(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var AdditionalTenentJsonList = JSON.stringify(AdditionalTenentList);

    alert(AdditionalTenentJsonList);

    var formURL = $(this).attr("action");


    $.ajax({
        url: formURL,
        type: "POST",
        data: { ApplicationModelData: $(this).serialize(), TenentJSONList: AdditionalTenentJsonList },
    }).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    //// my other code here.....
      }
</script>
```

In another function thats how I am pushing value to array

```
  AdditionalTenentList.StudentUWLID.push(StudentUWLID);
```

### Controller

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ApplyForAccommodation(AccommodationApplicationViewModel ApplicationModelData, string TenentJSONList)
    {

        return null;
    }
```

with the following code I get header response as

[image]

```
 $.ajax({
        url: formURL,
        type: "POST",
        dataType:"JSON",
        data: JSON.stringify({ TenentJSONList: AdditionalTenentList }),
    }).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
   ..........

   public ActionResult ApplyForAccommodation(string [] TenentJSONList)
    {
       var a = "d";

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle please for the client side part?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer as following;

```
 var AdditionalTenentList = new Array();

$('#CreateStudentRentingApplicationForm').submit(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var formURL = $(this).attr("action");

    var formData = $(this).serialize();


    $.ajax({
        url: formURL,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({ TenentJSONList: AdditionalTenentList, ApplicationModelData: $("#CreateStudentRentingApplicationForm").serializeObject() }),
    }).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

      //  .........my rest of code
```

...

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ApplyForAccommodation(string[] TenentJSONList, AccommodationApplicationViewModel ApplicationModelData)
    {
```